# Can Shimano Ultegra R8000 shifter be compatible with mechanical disc brake?

Tags: replacement

Im new in road bike and Shimano product as well.

I plan to own a China's make product which is Twitter R10 and i wish to change the existing groupset to Shimano R8000 groupset.

Here the problem
Twitter R10 is using mechanical disc brake. Is that possible Shimano Ultegra R8000 works with the mechanical disc brake?
http://www.twitterbike.com/entwviewbike/801.html    ----detail of the bike.
Some of the local shop told me yes.... some say no, i should go for R8020 instead of R8000. Anyhow, after some surveyed on internet,  i knew R8020 is for the hydraulic disc brake.

Hope experts from here able to give me some useful advise or anyone have experience this can share me the detail.

Thank you very much and happy riding

Comment: I’ve never heard of the components used on that bike but if the brakes are made for short pull they should work with any other (mechanical) road bike brake lever.

Answer (score 7):

This bike comes with cable-operated brakes. They are "hybrid" brakes, where a cable pulls a hydraulic plunger inside the caliper, which moves the pads. If you want to keep using those brakes, you'll need Ultegra levers for rim brakes.

If you want to use Ultegra disc brakes, the original equipment doesn't matter. You'll be getting Ultegra hydraulic levers and disc brake calipers. Shimano doesn't make mechanical disc brakes for Ultegra.

If you are going to keep the existing calipers, another question you should ask is whether Ultegra levers pull the same amount of brake cable as the original Sensah levers. If the cable pull is significantly different, the brakes will either grab early, or won't grab at all. I don't know the answer to that question, but my guess is that it won't be a problem.

I notice this bike is available in 3 different trim levels, one of them uses SRAM parts. SRAM disc brakes are hydraulic, but they are incompatible with Shimano hydraulic brakes--you can't combine Shimano levers and SRAM calipers. SRAM uses brake fluid and Shimano uses mineral oil as the hydraulic fluid, and if you use the wrong fluid, you can destroy the hydraulic seals. If you are thinking of getting this trim level, you would need to replace the calipers too.

Finally, buying a complete bike with parts you don't want, and then adding parts you do want, is generally an expensive way to get the bike you want. Unless you're getting an amazing deal on the bike or the parts, I recommend looking for something else.

Comment: *Cable-actuated hydraulic brakes* is the term I've heard used. Hybrid brakes is likely understandable but I think it's not a standard term. Good question about cable pull; Shimano STIs have a slightly different pull ratio than SRAM and Campy rim brake levers, and Sensah is thought to be ex-SRAM engineers so I'd guess they use SRAM's cable pull. This might lead to noticeably poorer performance. But it might not.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I've been running a set of SRAM Rival brakes with 105 levers for about a decade now without issue.  First with 5700 levers, and now with R7000s.  I've never even noticed the difference in pull.

Comment: Hi All , Thanks and appreciate for the feedback.  I will share you the result once i have. - using Ultegra r8000 with exisiting caliper

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Finally I have received my bike and the answer is:

**Ultegra R8000 shifter is compatible with the existing disc brake.**

Really appreciate for you guys useful information.
After few test rides, I have some feedback on the bike.

- I feel stiff on my neck,
- climb is disaster (probably i need to train more),
- brake is stiff,
- there is a friction between chainring and FD,
- shifting for chain gear is slow response.

Ok, i will go back to the shop for tuning

Another sharing is the total spent on the bike.
As mentioned before i bough some parts because I don't want the existing shifter, RD and FD.

R8000 shifter RM1090
R8000 RD RM304
R8000 FD RM178
R10 roadbike RM3550
bar tape RM40
= total RM5162 (1229USD)

Before I bought this bike, I have surveyed all the local shop include website. The bike come with those R8000 shifter, RD and FD cost RM5700 ++  (1357USD). Since I bought those R8000 and bike separately I saved a few hundred $$ yay.

Happy riding to all of you !!!

Comment: Thank you for the update and for closure.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks for modify my post. It looks better now